# Как сверстать элемент в виде капли?

Tags: css

Посоветуйте как или помогите сверстать вот такой эллипс
[image: screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
.vashElement {
    border-radius: 50% 0 50% 50%;
}
```

Comment: данный пример не 100% повторяет приведенное изображение, но если автору подойдет то ок)

Comment: Да вы правы. Результат будет похож на 99%. @Борис

Answer (score 4):

Ну если быть совсем точным, то можно и так:

```css
.cls{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  background: lightblue;
  border-radius: 100% 0% 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cls"></div>
```